# Imprime 3 líneas de resultados incluido un None

Tags: python, python-3.x

He realizado el programa siguiente para calcular el promedio y la desviación estándar. Al ejecutarlo por Pycharm me sale bien el resultado pero al parecer con otros compiladores imprime 3 líneas de resultados incluido un `None`. ¿Sabéis que estoy poniendo mal? ¿O podría hacerlo de otra forma mejor?

EL código es el siguiente:

```
def promedio_std(lista):
    l = len(lst)

    x = sum(lst)/l  # promedio

    cuadrados = []

    for d in lst:
        r = (d - x)**2  # dif. cuadrado

        cuadrados.append(r)

    y = (sum(cuadrados)/(l))**0.5 # desviacion


    return (x,y)

#bloque principal

lst =   [17, 97, 31, 99, 86, 19, 78, 68, 19, 45, 11, 5, 29, 76, 43, 97, 22, 57, 69]
print(promedio_std(lst))
```

Comment: Francisco no veo como ese código puede dar la salida que dices. ¿Es exactamente ese código el que da la salida inesperada? En cuanto a alternativas tienes el módulo [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#module-statistics) en Python >= 3.4, NumPy. En tu código se podrían usar generadores y algunas otras mejoras pero no hay nada incorrecto que justifique el comportamiento que dices tener. Python es un lenguaje interpretado, PyCharm no compila nada solo usa un intérprete instalado en tu SO para ejecutar el código. Ese código en cualquier máquina debe dar  la misma salida.

Comment: Si que hay diferencias entre Python 2 y Python 3 debido a la diferencia con el operador `/`. Supongo que tu código es para Python 3, porque en otro caso sería incorrecto ya que la media sería siempre un entero si la lista solo contiene enteros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la función llamas a la variable global, que probablemente sean tus None. Cambia los `lst` por `lista`,  que es como tienes llamado al parametro de tu función.

Prueba:

```
def promedio_std(lista):
    # lst por lista
    l = len(lista)

    # lst por lista
    x = sum(lista)/l  # promedio
    cuadrados = []

   # lst por lista 
   for d in lista:
        r = (d - x)**2  # dif. cuadrado
        cuadrados.append(r)
    y = (sum(cuadrados)/(l))**0.5 # desviacion
    return (x,y)

# bloque principal
lst = [17, 97, 31, 99, 86, 19, 78, 68, 19, 45, 11, 5, 29, 76, 43, 97, 22, 57, 69]
print(promedio_std(lst))
```

Aquí te dejo mi solución utilizando generadores:

```
def promedio_std(lista):
    l = len(lista)
    x = sum(lista) / l
    # generador
    cuadrados = [(d - x) **2 for d in lista] # dif. cuadrado
    y = (sum(cuadrados) / l) ** 0.5 # desviacion
    return (x, y)

#bloque principal

lista = [17, 97, 31, 99, 86, 19, 78, 68, 19, 45, 11, 5, 29, 76, 43, 97, 22, 57, 69]
print(promedio_std(lista))
```

Comment: En tu solución, el parámetro de la función es `l`. Y a continuación llamas a `lista` que es la variable global. ¿No estás cometiendo el mismo error que el usuario que ha hecho la pregunta?

Comment: Fue un despiste, gracias.